# "java.lang.RuntimeException: null" while querying with Reactive Mongo 0.11

Tags: mongodb, playframework, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

I'm trying to query a collection with findAll with `selector = {}` on JsonCollection with Play 2.4.2 and Reactive Mongo 0.11.5.

Query fails in method `foldM` deep inside the `play.api.libs.iteratee` while calling method `collect[List]`.

Last code that I could trace was `case Input.El(e) => { val newS = executeFuture(f(s, e))(pec); flatten(newS.map(s1 => Cont[E, A](step(s1)))(dec)) }`.

This code was ported from reactive mongo 0.10.5 and play 2.3.9.

The stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: null
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
        at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:396) ~[play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
        at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:389) ~[play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
        at play.api.libs.iteratee.StepIteratee$$anonfun$fold$2.apply(Iteratee.scala:706) ~[play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
        at play.api.libs.iteratee.StepIteratee$$anonfun$fold$2.apply(Iteratee.scala:706) ~[play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
        at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.executeScheduled(Execution.scala:109) ~[play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
        at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:71) ~[play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:153) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:23) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$AdaptedForkJoinTask.exec(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:121) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with DateTime format I used to work with mongo dates in a format `{ date: { $date: 1435723470549 } }`.

This question explains the difference: [Parsing a Json String in Scala using Play framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31690886/parsing-a-json-string-in-scala-using-play-framework), I should have updated it to use `JsDefined`.